# How to change amazon aws S3 time zone setting for a bucket

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

My server time is set as Asia/India. So when ever I am trying to post an image in S3 bucket I am getting the following error

`RequestTimeTooSkewed`The difference between the request time and the current time is too large.Thu, 09 Jul 2015 17:53:21 GMT2015-07-09T08:23:22Z90000068B8486508D2695Ag6EfiNV8uJi8JY/Y2JWCIBi7fROEa/Uw2Yaw3fw3pfAbI+ZtaFZV7PnHhZ6Yxw07

How can I change the AWS S3 bucket time as IST?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with timezone of machine or S3 bucket, your machine time is not correct and if machine time is off by more than 15 minutes, AWS will give error because of security. Just check if time is correct on machine.

Comment: There is no way to set the timezone on an S3 bucket.  AWS expects your requests to use a UTC timestamp and it requires it to be reasonable close to the actual time (either 15 minutes for older signature versions or 5 minutes for signature V4).  Either you have set the machine time on your computer to the wrong time zone or the time has drifted beyond the acceptable window.  Fix the time on your local machine and it will fix the problem.